# Asp.Net Form Authentication : Session change to other recently login user session automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, iis-8, asp.net-session

My asp.net webform application Hosted on IIS8 in **intranet** with **Form authentication**. For a single user at a time, this application is working completely fine. But problem is with more than one user. Taking example of two users to explain the problem.

***The problem is when UserA login to the application and perform any navigation. At the same time other UserB login to the application and perform any navigation. Now at the same time if userA refresh there browser then UserA realize that his session converted into the UserB session(loggedin recently), which is strange and odd as well.*** Both user on different machine/system and location. I don't know what should i call this problem.

I think there is some point that i am missing in my configuration/code. My code and configuration given below.

In C#, after validating the user credentials, i am using below piece of code
`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserId, false);`

In Web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>    
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="LogIn.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" path="/" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Welcome.aspx" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I am accessing my Hosted application with the following URL:

http://SERVER_NAME:8020/LogIn.aspx

Please suggest, what i am doing wrong or missing any important step.

Comment: This has got me intrested. i would suggest you to note down the SessionID cookie value from a user and then perform refresh operation and see if that cookie value changes after the refresh. I have not seen anything like this before.

Comment: I suspect that no session switching is happening. I don't know, but my guess is that you are using some global state (application scope, class with static properties or some such) which is updated when user B logs in, then shown also for user A when he/she does something that refreshes the hie/her browser page.

Comment: Hi @GaganDeep, There is no change in cookie value after refresh ctrl+f5, i checked in chrome->f12>Application tab.

Comment: Without cookie change session cannot be hijacked. So I also think it is some server side code that is doing it for you. Are you storing something in session variables. What are those. How are those set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the `SessionID` after logged on successfully so that verify these sessions are the same.
Besides, there is a possibility that generating same authentication ticket during the redirection logic. It depends on how we control cookie generation.

```
  private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
   {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
      string cookiestr;
      HttpCookie ck;
      tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
      cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
      ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
      if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
      ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;
    ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
      Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

      string strRedirect;
      strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
      if (strRedirect==null)
            strRedirect = "default.aspx";
         Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
   }
   else
      Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
}
```

Check this for more details.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.